# Xcode media player monitor

Tags: xcode, media-player, movie

how to monitor the media player per second, so you can, depending on the video time to perform the action?

Solutions may be with timer, but I hope for a standard method.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "MediaPlayer"? Are talking about a QTMovieView ([QTMovieView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/quicktime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))?

If so, you can get the QTMovie object by calling:

```
[myQTMovieView movie]
```

and then get its

```
[aMovie currentTime]
```

Please note that this only applies to OS X and not to iOS. Please specify more details about your question.

Comment: I mean MPMoviePlayerController, but I can use QTMovieView, if it's better
But I program for iOS